# Can't Access Admin Panel after changing Base URL in Magento 2.1.3

Tags: php, magento-2.1.3, admin-login

I made a mistake. I changed the Admin Base URL and now I can't access the admin site.

In the `core_config_data` table,I edited the following rows in the database:

**Scope**:`"Default"` and **Path**:`"admin/url/custom"`

Select the `NULL` checkbox and save.

**Scope**:`"Default"` and **Path**:`"admin/url/use_custom"`

Change value from `1 to 0` and save.

I deleted the following rows:

**Scope**:`"Stores"` and **Path**:`"web/secure/base_url"`
**Scope**:`"Stores"` and **Path**:`"web/unsecure/base_url"`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert again "web/secure/base_url" and "web/unsecure/base_url", it's your store frontend URL (not admin).

Don't forget to clear your cache from command line:

`php bin/magento cache:clean`
`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: Ok. but I can still the store with no problem. The admin though. Localhost isn't working.

Comment: Can you run this SQL command and show the results please:
`SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%base%url%';`

Comment: I post the screenshot of the result.

Comment: Perfect! You welcome!